# How can I install GNOME without installing the default applications?

Tags: gnome, software-installation, desktop-environments

I want to install the GNOME desktop environment, but I don't want to install all the applications that follows if I `apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop --no-install-recommends
```

Comment: This command installs 672 new packages (211MB download, 881MB hard disk usage).

Answer (score 2):

There is also the `gnome-session` package that will install GNOME without any additional apps.